# Seconds scalar is always null in vue-apollo

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, vue-apollo, graphql-dotnet

I'm trying to pass an int value as seconds scalar to my graphql-backend.
The frontend uses vue-apollo and the backend is written in dotnet core using graphql-dotnet.

When I call the mutation via playground, everything works fine. Neither does my vue app throw any error/exception nor works the mutation. The mutation is called in the backend, but the value for `s` is null (and so 00:00:00 as it is a TimeSpan). The backend is written in dotnet core 3.1 but as I said the convertion from a given number to TimeSpanSecondsGraphType works via playground.

**frontend code**

My mutation looks like

```
updateS(
  sId: ID = null
  s: s = null
): SType
```

My input type s looks like

```
type s {
  s: Seconds = null
}
```

And my SType looks like

```
type SType {
  s: Seconds
}
```

Working example call (via playground)

```
mutation {
  updateS(s: "08d924e8-69fb-425c-8130-de7342a2ca2a", s: {
    s: 3600
  }) {
    s
  }
}
```

This is the payload from chrome when I call the mutation in my vue-app (not working):

```
{"operationName":"updateS","variables":{"sId":"08d924e8-69fb-425c-8130-de7342a2ca2a","s":{"s":3600}},"query":"mutation updateS($sId: ID!, $s: s!) {\n  updateS(sId: $sId, s: $s) {\n   s\n__typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

**Edit - Added backend code**

**dotnet core mutation and models**

This is my mutation in the backend:

```
Field<SType>(
                "updateS",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<IdGraphType> { Name = "sId" },
                    new QueryArgument<SInputType> { Name = "s" }
                ),
                resolve: context =>
                {
                    var sId = context.GetArgument<Guid>("sId");
                    var s = context.GetArgument<S>("s"); // s.S is always {00:00:00} when called from vue app. 
                    return repo.UpdateS(sId, s);
                });
```

My `SInputType`:

```
public class SInputType : InputObjectGraphType
    {
        public SInputType()
        {
            Name = "s";
            Field<TimeSpanSecondsGraphType>("s");
        }
    }
```

And my `S.cs`:

```
public class S
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan S { get; set; }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you tried in the graphql playground?

Comment: Yes, the working example works fine in playground. So I guess it's a bug in vue-apollo or a mistake i've made.

Comment: Do you have the correct payload sent from the client? Check what is your payload in your chrome network tab. Also, what exactly is not working?

Comment: The payload is the last snippet in my question. That payload works also fine in playground. Whenever that query is called in my vue app the value for the Seconds scalar (in my case 3600) is not parsed to DateTimeSecondsGraphTyp and I get 0 as value.

Comment: Uh sorry, what do you have as a response there so? Also, does it work with Insomnia or any other software that can send a GQL query?

Comment: I added the code for the backend to clarify the problem (see comment in the mutation). It works fine with Postman and Insomnia.